# Eclipse Updating Java Runtime Enviroment Not Working

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-8

I am using a mac and tried to update java (from 7 to 8). I downloaded the Java SE Development Kit 8 and installed it on eclipse by doing preferences-Java-Installed JRE'S-Add- Standard VM-Directories, etc. And checked the Java 1.8 box.

I also made sure that Preferences-Java-Compiler had 1.8 selected.

However, when I run java 8 code I still get an UnsupportedClassVersionError. At the top of the console it says:

**Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/vin.java**

How do I change that to 1.8 instead of 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Properties for your project and select 'Java Build Path'. Look on the 'Libraries' tab and see what you have selected for the 'JRE System Library'. Use the Edit... button to change this entry to be Java 8.

[image: Java Build Path]

Comment: Under 'Java Build Path' I don't have JRE System Library. I only have  'User Libraries', which has nothing about java 8 in it.

Comment: You did create this as a Java Project? I can't see a way to create a Java Project without this entry.

Comment: Yes, a Java project without a JRE System Library is a mystery, but this can be fixed by hitting `Add Library...` and selecting `JRE System Library`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Eclipse --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs
```

There you can install different JDKs.

In the directory: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine`
you'll find all your installed JDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my specific problem. All I had to do was go to installed JRE's and delete all of them except for Java 8. Thanks to all of you who tried to help, it was much appreciated.